# Create a function that consumes a list of cards and produces a list of those cards which are red and odd

Tags: python, class

I have to write the function red_odd, which consumes a list of cards, hand, and produces a list of those cards which are red (i.e., "diamonds" or "hearts") and have an odd value, in the order they appear in the consumed list. The consumed list cannot be mutated.

For example,

red_odd([card1, card2, card3, card4]) => [card2]

So I have this so far:

```
class card:
    'Fields: suit, value'
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

card1 = card('spades', 8) 
card2 = card('hearts', 5) 
card3 = card('diamonds', 6) 
card4 = card('clubs', 5)

def red_odd(hand):
    card_list = []
    for c in hand:
        if (c.suit == 'diamonds' or c.suit == 'hearts')  and (c.value / 2 != 0):
            card_list.append(c)
    return card_list
```

It doesn't run and I'm not sure where I went wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: your division is incorrect. e.g. a 10 will come out as `10 / 2` -> `5 != 0`. You need to check the modulo, e.g. `10 % 2 == 0` for evens. `!=` for odds.

Comment: This _runs_ just fine; you just never actually call your function. Though your math is wrong (you need `c.value % 2` instead of `c.value / 2`)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call your function:

```
odd_red_cards = red_odd([card1,card2,card3,card4])
print(odd_red_cards)
```

That'll give you a little more to debug.

---

Note that it might be useful to add a `__str__` or `__repr__` function to allow your cards to print a little more naturally which could be useful for finding other bugs down the road.  e.g.:

```
class card(object):
     ...
     def __repr__(self):
         return '{suit} {value}'.format(suit=self.suit,value=self.value)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: he needs a `__str__` method in his `card` class for this to print anything useful.